# Shortage of breath - is this a sign of overtraining

Tags: bicycling, breathing, heart-rate, overtraining

I know there are lots of QAs available on over training and shortage of breath, but I could not find specific answers to my doubts/problems. I know few things cant be decided over a forum and I may need to consult a doctor; just want to clear my doubts before I take any decisions.

I have been training from past 4 months and my training involves 45-60 mins of cardio (2-3 times a week) and strengthening exercise (5 times a week). For cardio I'm doing  Spinning (indoor cycling) and I was doing good progress. However couple of weeks back while Spinning I was stretching myself a bit hard and at one point I felt shortage of breath and heart rate shot up and I felt faint and dizzy. Immediately I stopped cycling at that moment.

Now the problem is whenever I start cardio, I feel shortage of breath and breathing difficulty very soon and feel like my heart is pounding very fast though my muscles are not very tired. Because of this I have to slow down else I fear of fainting.

Is it because of over training? Did I damage my lungs or heart because of this? I'm bit scared to get back into hard training. Is there anything that I have to consider before getting back to training as before (I know doctor's consultation is one of it)

Comment: These are good questions for your doctor.  Because you have noticed a change and have felt shortness of breath, faint and dizzy, your best course is to have your doctor check you out to be safe, before you resume exercise. Your doctor will then make appropriate recommendations.

Comment: You have the symptoms of tachycardia, a potentially life threatening disorder and should talk to a doctor immediately.

Comment: Could be. Have you had any rest days?

Comment: Yes @SeanDuggan, I have had rest days of some 2-3 days before getting back on cardio, but was continuing with strength training.

Comment: Yeah. I'm going to have to go with that this is a case where you really want to see a doctor.

Comment: I had similar symptoms last year and talked to my cardiologist immediately.  Found out I had a birth defect, and pushing my heart rate over a certain threshold would cause the same symptoms to return.  When doing cardio work, I now have to use a heart rate monitor and back off if I get too close to the threshold.  Otherwise I'm perfectly healthy.  However, only my cardiologist could tell me what was going on.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have  Booked an appointment with my GP, hope they guide me through. Just hoping that its nothing major to worry about.